# Add a class on hover remove class on second hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class on hover but not remove it when mouse leaves. Instead it must be removed on the second mouse hover. So on mouse hover add class. Mouse leaves class remains. Mouse hovers again class is removed.

This code adds the class but if the mouse leaves the class is removed which is not what I'm trying to achieve.

```
jQuery('.menuButton').hover(function(){
  jQuery('.mainMenuDrop').addClass('show')
}, function() {
  jQuery('.mainMenuDrop').removeClass('show')
});
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: [mouseenter](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [toggleclass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: Post your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your requirement of add on first entry and remove on second entry, you can change your existing code:

```
jQuery('.menuButton').hover(function(){
  jQuery('.mainMenuDrop').addClass('show')
}, function() {
  jQuery('.mainMenuDrop').removeClass('show')
});
```

to use .toggleClass

```
jQuery('.menuButton').hover(function(){
  jQuery('.mainMenuDrop').toggleClass('show')
}, function() {
  // nothing here
});
```

---

As jquery `.hover` binding is just syntax for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` and you don't need `mouseleave`, this can be simplified to:

```js
jQuery('.menuButton').on("mouseenter", function() {
  jQuery('.mainMenuDrop').toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
div { border: 1px solid black; padding: 20px; width: 100px; }
.show { background-color: pink; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='menuButton'>point at me</div>
<div class='mainMenuDrop'>changes here</div>
```